# Wordpress Gantry - how to split up mainbody in 2 ?

Tags: wordpress

Gantry for wordpress question :

Ive fallen in love with Gantry - wordpress theme, its really smooth and configuarable. I dont use it as a base for a blog but instead a simple webpage.

But have one problem that i cant figure out, i can configure all elements like the header, logo, navigation, etc. and splut them up in several elements.

But Content ( the pages ) will always show as one full width element in the middle, what i really would like to do is to split up the main body into 2 "tables" whereas content only shows in ex. a 400 pixel widht box, and then have a picture shown pr. page in the remaining est. 300 pixels on the right.

In the gantry settings menu i can go in and adjust "mainbody" but it just doesnt seem to work for content at all nomatter what i set it to and dont know how to be able to add an element to it as "mainbody" is not a widget you can configure.

Hope someone can help - thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can split main component into two positions, however you can use sidebars  or you can use main-body-top and main-body-bottom positions last two can be splitted up to the 3 exact same positions ... my best advice would be that u use sidebars .. which widths and positions you can then manage in the theme settings.